# How to clear search area when using selenium for web scraping

Tags: python, selenium, textarea, webdriverwait

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import requests


driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.set_window_size(800,600)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get('https://news.google.com/?hl=ko&gl=KR&ceid=KR%3Ako')
driver.implicitly_wait(2)

words = ['atom','mechanic','clock']

for word in words:

    if datetime.datetime.today()==0:
        word = word+'when:3d'
    else:
        word = word +'when:1d'

    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gb"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/input[2]')
    elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a' + Keys.NULL, word.decode('utf-8'))

    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Above is the entire script for web scraping the rest is working fine but this part, `elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a' + Keys.NULL, word.decode('utf-8'))`, doesn't do anything. Any tips on how to fix this to clear search area for next words?

Answer (score 0):

To clear the search area when using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the`element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='gb']/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/input[2]")))
  element.click()
  element.clear()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```